# Invalid syntax with path in Django 3.1.5

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a syntax error even though I've checked the code many times.
I'm new with Django so I'm not sure if I'm missing something else.
So this is my code in my urls.py:

```
# Django
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

# media
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # Admin url path
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    # Posts url paths
    path('', include(('posts.urls', 'posts'), namespace='posts')),
    # User url paths
    path('users/', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I'm following a tutorial and I've literally copy-pasted what was working for the tutor and it throws the same error as shown below.

```
File "/home/juandev/apps/platzigram/platzigram/urls.py", line 15, in <module>
    path('users/', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')),
  File "/home/juandev/ENTER/envs/djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/juandev/ENTER/envs/djangoenv/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 786, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 923, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/juandev/apps/platzigram/users/urls.py", line 19
    path(
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas what this might be?

Edit:

My users/urls.py looked like this:

```
# Django
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Views
from users import views

urlpatterns = [

    # Posts
    path(
        route='profile/<str:username>/',
        view= TemplateView.as_view(template_name='users/detail.html'),
        name='detail'
    )

    # User management
    path(
        route='login/', 
        view=views.login_view, 
        name='login'
    ),
    path(
        route='logout/', 
        view=views.logout_view, 
        name='logout'
    ),
    path(
        route='signup/',
        view=views.signup,
        name='signup'
    ),
    path(
        route='me/profile',
        view=views.update_profile,
        name='update_profile'
    ),
]
```

Thansk to Chris for pointing out the error wasn't in my main urls.py file, i was missing a , in this other file.

Comment: The problem isn't in that file. Your error message refers to the URLs file _in your users app_ (`users/urls.py`), not the project-level one. Please [edit] your question and show us that fiile.

Comment: Also, [please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You're missing a comma on the previous code line: the posts `path(...)` should be `path(...),`.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for the help, it's my first time posting on here so I'll have your pointers for the next time.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got this solved!